# Component communication in Vue.js unable to render properly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In the **Parent component** I have:

```
<todo-item v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.id" :todo="todo" :index="index">

</todo-item>
```

which just iterates through `todos` array and gets each `todo object` and by using `props` passes each Object and its index to the child component.  `todo-item` registered in Child component.
`todos` is an array of objects:

```
todos: [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'title': 'Object 1'
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'title': 'Object 2'
        }
      ]
```

**Child component:**

```
<template>
    <div class="todo-item">
         <div class="todo-item-left">
            <div>{{ todo.title }}</div>
       </div>

    </div>
</template>>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'todo-item',
    props: {
        todo: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        index: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't know why it doesn't render each todo on the page, I have a blank page. Even though in Vue DevTools It shows that I have these objects.
[image: Vue DevTools inspection]
Did I miss something?

**EDIT:**
There is an error, sorry the error flag were off hence didn't saw it.
Error message:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

As you can see above I did register the component in Child component.
And yes I did import the child component in Parent component by doing:

```
//Parent component
import ToDoItem from './ToDoItem'  
export default {
  name: 'todo-list',
  components: {
    ToDoItem,
  },
```

Comment: is there any errors?

Comment: are you sure you imported & used the child component correctly?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  yes, please see the updated question

Comment: please share the parent component script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with cases so you should import that component in parent one as follows :

```
 import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
```

and register it like :

```
export default{
  ....
components:{
       TodoItem
    }
 ....
 }
```

for more details check [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing)

Comment: As you can see in my question post, I did import and registered in this way. But I just now saw ur answer and tried to change as you did from ToDoItem  => TodoItem.  And it starts working ! Why it would care how i write it ? so weird

Comment: Initially, I wrote: import ToDoItem from './ToDoItem'  components: {
    ToDoItem,
  }

Comment: then i just did: import TodoItem from './ToDoItem' components: { TodoItem, }

Comment: and the last one work just changed from capital D to small d.

Comment: your component is named `todo-item` with cabab-case format which will be converted to camelCase format

Comment: it capitalize the first letter and every letter after the dash `-`

Comment: never heard about it. will do some research. Thnx !

Answer (score 0):

### a common mistake

### dont forget import child component in parent component

```js
import ChildComponent fromt './ChildComponent';
export default{
components:{
       ChildComponent 
    }
 }
```